# ¿Por qué "vacunar" significa "mentir"?

Tags: significado, argentina, chile, acepciones

El otro día viendo los comentarios de un post de YouTube me encontré con el siguiente comentario:

[image]

> *Transcripción de la parte relevante:* (Aclaro que en Argentina, de donde soy oriunda ,  una de las acepciones del verbo "vacunar " tiene el significado de MENTIR). "Me han vacunado"  es un eufemismo de ME HAN MENTIDO o ME HAN VENDIDO GATO POR LIEBRE

Esta acepción es coherente con la acepción de "[vacunar](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=vacuna)" del diccionario de americanismos (aunque el diccionario lo registra como un *chilenismo*).

> 2. Ch. Estafa, fraude. pop + cult → espon.
> 3. adj/sust. Ch. meton. Referido a persona, que se dedica a estafar o perpetrar fraudes. pop + cult → espon.

La acepción primera, relativa a la extorsión no me parece tan sorprendente desde el punto de vista de la ironía. Alguien que te extorsiona puede decir que ahora estás "vacunado" o "protegido" contra los accidentes (esos "accidentes" que *solo* se producirían de no pagar...). La acepción de "mentir" me cuesta un poco más imaginarme de dónde puede venir.

¿Cómo ha llegado "vacunar" a significar "mentir" o "engañar"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En Argentina se usa mucho con el sentido de "perjudicar", no tanto "estafar".

En el *Diccionario etimológico del lunfardo* encontramos la siguiente entrada:

[image: vacunar]

Y en [este otro sitio](http://www.jergasdehablahispana.org/index.php?pais=Argentina&palabra=vacunar&tipobusqueda=1) encontramos algunos buenos ejemplos:

[image: vacunar]

Answer (score 5):

Parece que la etimología a propósito es poco clara, viniendo de una jerga chilena llamada *coa*:

> Finalmente, en Chile existe también una jerga carcelaria y de delincuencia llamada *coa*,
>   que parece haber tomado muchas expresiones del lunfardo argentino. Esta jerga se ha
>   difun-dido entre los jóvenes, de modo que muchas de sus expresiones son hoy bastante
>   comunes en el habla popular y en los registros menos formales: *abrir el tarro* 'delatar',
>   'hablar mucho'; *a todo mórrison* 'a todo ritmo'; *brígido* 'peligroso'; luca 'billete de mil pesos'; *mitimota* 'a medias'; *papaya* 'fácil'; *tallarín* 'cicatriz en la cara'; *vacuna* 'estafa'; *volón* 'juerga', 'viaje'.
>
> - [Variedades de la lengua española](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WmPBDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT156&lpg=PT156&dq=chile+%22vacuna%22+%22estafa%22)

> Many of the popular words that Chileans use today,
>   though, do have humble and racy origins. The
>   dialect of *coa* frequently seeps into Chilean speech,
>   constituting a notable source of Chilenismos. *Coa*
>   originally developed in jails where inmates used it
>   as a code so that guards could not understand what
>   they were saying. Delinquents on the street also
>   used specially invented words so that police and
>   others could not understand them.
>
> - [Chilenismos: a Dictionary and Phrasebook for Chilean Spanish](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dWrjMRN_zjcC&pg=PP19&lpg=PP19&dq=chile+coa)

Comment: Gracias por el pointer al phrasebook de chilenismos!